# как можно организовать логаут после timeout в jsf?

Tags: java, servlet, jsf

У меня есть обычная страница авторизации на сервере.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>#{loginMsg.title}</h1>

        <form name="login" id="login" action="/cms/j_security_check" method="post">

            <h:outputText value="#{loginMsg.try_again}" styleClass="error"
                          rendered="#{param.error}"/>

            <table class="auth">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="username">#{loginMsg.login}</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="j_username" />
                        <span id="loginError" class="error" style="display: none;">
                            <br/>
                            #{commonMsg.empty_field_error}
                        </span>

                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="password">#{loginMsg.password}</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="j_password" />
                        <span id="passwordError" class="error" style="display: none;">
                            <br/>
                            #{commonMsg.empty_field_error}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" onclick="return auth();" class="login">
                            #{loginMsg.enter}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="return checkForm();"/>
        </form>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="/cms/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("div#outer").addClass('auth');
                var regEx = /^.*MSIE [1-6]\.\d{1}.*$/;
                if (navigator.userAgent.match(regEx)) {
                    window.location = "/cms/403.xhtml"
                }
            });

            jQuery('input').keypress(function(e){
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if(code == 13){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    auth();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });

            function auth() {
                if (checkForm()) {
                    document.forms['login'].submit();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            function checkForm() {
                var res = true;

                jQuery("#loginError").hide();
                jQuery("#passwordError").hide();
                if (!jQuery("#username").val()) {
                    jQuery("#loginError").show();
                    res = false;
                }
                if (!jQuery("#password").val()) {
                    jQuery("#passwordError").show();
                    res = false;
                }

                return res;
            }
        </script>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

После авторизации setMaxInactiveInterval не устанавливается. Устанавливается только после выхода из профиля( и получается что сессия начинается при выходе из профиля и вовзвращаешься на страницу с логином и паролем.

У меня написан

```
public class HttpSessionTimeoutListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        String strLogout = Optional.ofNullable(SystemProperties.get("cms.logout_time")).orElseGet(() -> "10");

        try {
            System.out.println(new Integer(strLogout));
            httpSessionEvent.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(new Integer(strLogout));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            getLogger().error("e");
        }
    }
```

и лисенер к нему.

```
  <listener>
    <listener -class>com.bifit.cms.utils.HttpSessionTimeoutListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Почему оно так работает? как мне реализовать логаут? помогите, очень нужно((лемы. Необходимо как-то организовать логаут